# Does Inheritance only work in one Direction?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Just when I thought I had understood inheritance, I get stuck on a problem...

Let's say I've got an abstract class Animal and several derived classes, like this:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Age{get;set;}
    public abstract bool Hungry{get;set;}

};

public class Dog:Animal
{
    public bool PottyTrained{get;set;}
}
public class Cat:Animal
{
    public int MiceKilled{get;set;}
}
```

I now want a method that can handle both Dogs and Cats. I thought I could do it like this:

```
public List<Animal> FeedAnimals(List<Animal> InAnimals)
{
    foreach(var animal in InAnimals)
    {
        animal.Hungry = false;
    }
    return InAnimals;
}
```

but when I try it, the compiler tells me "cannot convert from ..." ...

Am I doing something wrong? Is this because I'm passing lists? Any way around it?

Comment: `the compiler tells me "cannot convert from ..." ...` What **exactly** did it tell you?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like you don't want the properties to be abstract - only the class.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to pass in a `List<Dog>` instead of a `List<Animal>` but with you mysteriously not showing us that code, we can't tell. Also not clear why the two properties are abstract, it makes your code not compile.

Comment: What is the exact error? Which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: Just because `Dog` is a `Animal` it does not mean that `List<Dog>` is a `List<Animal>`. It is not.

Comment: @mjwills : My VS isn't in English so that won't help you but roughly it's "Type System.Collections.Generic.List<abstract class> can't be converted to GenericList<derived Class> implicitly.

Comment: @Enigmativity Is there any way I can implement whatever kind of Interface VS needs to convert the data from one List Type to another?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate link @Vaethin?

Comment: @Vaethin You can do `List<Animal> animals = listOfDogs.Cast<Animal>().ToList();`. That makes a copy of your list - but beware that since you've now made a list of animals you can also now add cats to the list.